# What is the best way to remove a specificed phrase from a string?

Tags: rust

So if I have a string: `let foo = "test/string/plz"`, and I wanted to remove "string", what would be the best way to do so? I have devised a solution below:

```
fn delete_phrase(input: String, find: String) -> String{
    let mut temp = input.clone();
    
    if input.contains(&find){
        let index = input.find(&find);
        for _i in 0..find.len(){
            temp.remove(index.unwrap());
        }
    }

    return temp.to_string();
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should probably first check if the input doesn't contain `find`, so you don't do an unnecessary clone.

Comment: You could also return a `Cow<str>`, then when the string you're searching for is at the start, end, or is the whole input, you can return a borrowed version. Also instead of removing characters one at a time (causing a possible `O(N^2)` blowup), instead you should probably append everything before the match to everything after the match and return that.

Comment: You seem to be looking for [`String::replacen()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replacen) (assuming you only want to remove the first occurrence of `find`, otherwise just use `replace()`).

Comment: `find` should be a `&str` instead of a `String`, and `input` either a `Cow<str>` or a `&str`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We can use [if let](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html) to greatly reduce the code to just an if-else statement:

```rs
fn delete_phrase(input: String, find: String) -> String {
    if let Some(index) = input.find(&find) {
        let left = &input[0..index];
        let right = &input[index + find.len()..];
        
        return [left, right].concat();
    } else {
        return input;
    }
}
```

Then, we're taking @FilipeRodrigues's suggestion and using slices to get everything before and after the match. After that, we just need to join the slices together.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=45ee9e64a8c43ec1ecda6a7c8da0af8f)